# Out of memory on loading a Image with System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, image, memory, image-size

```
System.Drawing.Image original = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(photo);
```

That's the code where i have the problem "`Out of memory`."

"`photo`" is a path of an image which the size is `6400x6400`.

Have anyone idea about that?

Comment: What language/framework? Add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this C#?  I think the answer may be here.

[out of memory Image.FromFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848132/out-of-memory-image-fromfile)

Top Answer from user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/31158/jordao

> In the `Image.FromFile` documentation, an `OutOfMemoryException` can be throw if:
>
> > The file does not have a valid image format.
> >
> > -or-
> >
> > GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.
>
> Check your image format.
>
> Also, if you want to close the stream right after loading the image, you must make a copy of the image. Take a look here. GDI+ must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the image.

Another top answer and thread to consider then:

[Out Of Memory exception on System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108607/out-of-memory-exception-on-system-drawing-image-fromfile)

From user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

> It's worth knowing that OutOfMemoryException doesn't always really mean it's out of memory - particularly not when dealing with files. I believe it can also happen if you run out of handles for some reason.
>
> Are you disposing of all your bitmaps after you're done with them? Does this happen repeatably for a single image?

Also, I would add- have you saved this file out using your code and tried to view it in another image viewer?  It may be corrupt if it is being created incorrectly.

Comment: The format of the image is *.jpg and it created of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume this is in C#, is your code is in a loop or in the `Paint` event? This could explain why it is not working. If you load several images or a single image multiple times, you will of course encounter a "Out of memory" Exception.

Comment: It's only one image and one time