# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: asp.net, winforms, memory

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the below code i am having no joy figuring this out. I am disposing and have in a using block but keep getting this exception

> An unhandled exception of type '`System.OutOfMemoryException`' occurred in `System.Drawing.dll`
>
> Additional information: Out of memory.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    Regex re = new Regex("original", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (re.IsMatch(file.FullName)) continue;

    using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file.FullName))
    {
        if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
        {
            filesJpeg.Add(file);
            img.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            img.Dispose();
            File.Delete(file.FullName);
        }
 
        img.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are disposing img inside `using` block. It will automatically done after `using` call ends

Comment: I had no disposing and was getting the error as didnt think was neccessary so added also and still got same error.

Comment: Which line you got the exception

Comment: System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file.FullName)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842708/out-of-memory-on-loading-a-image-with-system-drawing-image  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108607/out-of-memory-exception-on-system-drawing-image-fromfile

Answer (score 1):

The `OutOfMemoryException` when opening images might not necessarily mean it's out of memory. It may mean the image format is unknown, or not supported by GDI+ .

As per the documentation (on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx):

> **Exception**
>
> OutOfMemoryException
>
> **Condition**
>
> The file does not have a valid image format.
>
> -or-
>
> GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

I'd check the file where it's throwing the exception and see if it's in a strange format