# How to skip a file with an invalid PixelFormat in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, gdi+, pixelformat

I have a simple program that iterates through a list of images, checks the width and height of the images, and then moves them to a specified folder depending on the outcome.  I'm using `Image.FromFile(path)` to check the images, and once it hits specific images I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

This potential causes for this error have already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3848178/3605237)

```
string directory = @"C:\foo\bar\";

foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || s.EndsWith(".tif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{

    //exception thrown here, at Image.FromFile
    Image i = Image.FromFile(path);

    if (i.Width > i.Height)
    {
        i.Dispose();
        File.Move(path, directory + @"horizontal\" + path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        i.Dispose();
        File.Move(path, directory + @"vertical\" + path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(@"\")));
    }

}
```

I know for certain the *cause* of the error, some of the TIFF images it's hitting (for some absurd reason!) have a bit depth of 40, which is not a valid GDI+ pixel format, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) for reference.

I can get around the problem with try-catch (`OutOfMemoryException`), but I'd much check the images for a valid pixel format rather than hope I don't get the exception for any other reason.

Comment: looks like there is a [`fromstream(stream,bool,bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6.aspx) that throws argument exception if the imige is invalid

Comment: TIFF == Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  Catch and continue.