# System.Drawing.Image.FromFile "System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory."

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, system.drawing

I get these errors every once in a while and I am not sure why.  This code executes thousands of times a day and Ill get these errors every once in a while.  One of the images is 94.9 KB, 1024x1024 image.  The image is being read from an `Azure File Storage` disk via `UNC` Path.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.

Generated: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 15:09:54 GMT

System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
   at Tournaments.ImageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\Development\Exposure\Main\Websites\Tournaments\ImageHandler.ashx.cs:line 64
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**Actual Code**

```
 using (var image = Image.FromFile(path))
 {
 }
```

Comment: It suggests there is a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: I posted the code above.  Memory leak within the .NET framework?

Comment: The memory leak is likely in `Tournaments.ImageHandler.ProcessRequest`, however, this can also be caused by a image that is just too large, or that has bad header data.

Comment: Well I opened the same URL in the browser and loaded fine.  It is a big image though but why would this cause this?  The image really isnt that large as I posted a size of one above.

Comment: It always looks like a library problem. You should take a heap dump and look at classes that are part of your application namespace. The problem usually occurs in application code.

Comment: Note that GDI+ is really bad at identifying the reason for the OutOfMemoryException.
It could be that the Image Header is currupted, or a number of different reasons!
Check out the answer on [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848132/out-of-memory-image-fromfile) question!

Comment: What is the handler doing with the image after it's loaded? Since you are loading it as an image rather than just as a file, you are probably manipulating it somehow. The manipulation code may be leaking memory if you are not consistently `using` every `IDisposable` object you create...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to fix my issue as it doesn't hold a reference to it this way.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
                {
                  
                    byte[] bytes;

                
                      
                        using (var memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            image.Save(memoryStream1, GetImageFormat(Path.GetExtension(path)));
                            bytes = memoryStream1.ToArray();
                        }
                    

                }
            }
    }
    
      private ImageFormat GetImageFormat(string extension)
            {
                switch (extension.ToLower())
                {
                    case ".png":
                        return ImageFormat.Png;
                    default:
                        return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                }
            }
```

Comment: This fix did not work for me. I have the same access denied or Out of Memory error as if I used `using (Image MyImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FileName))` or `using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))`

Comment: Looks like I am using different code now.