# Opening 32-bit float image causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, image, floating-point

I am running a console application in Visual Studio 2017 RC. When executing the code below I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'` exception.

The image im trying to load is a 32-bit float image.
Loading a 16-bit float image works fine.

I have tried setting the **Plattform** type to `x64`in the *Configuration Manager*.

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleAppImageTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string PathToFile = @"D:\img\rgb32bitF.tiff";
            Image img = Image.FromFile(PathToFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Color or black?

Comment: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1). Plain white. Where do I upload files to for stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Try [LibTiff.NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) for handling TIFF images.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285521/6879283) provides a solution to opening (32-bit) tiffs (as suggested by [M Adeel Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4283590/m-adeel-khalid)).

Add a the **PresentationCore** reference and `using  System.Windows.Media.Imaging;`.

```
 string PathToFile = @"D:\img\rgb32bitF.tiff";
 Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(PathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
 TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
 BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
```