# How to create a Bitmap deep copy

Tags: c#, bitmap, deep-copy

I'm dealing with Bitmaps in my application and for some purposes I need to create a deep copy of the Bitmap. Is there an elegant way how to do it?

I tried

```
Bitmap deepCopy = original.Clone();
```

,well apparently this doesn't create a deep copy, but shallow one.
My next attempt was to create a new Bitmap

```
Bitmap deepCopy = new Bitmap(original);
```

Unfortunately this constructor is Bitmap(Image), not Bitmap(Bitmap) and Bitmap(Image) will convert my nice 8bppIndexed Pixelformat into a different one.

Another attempt was to use of a MemoryStream

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmapDeepCopy(Bitmap source)
{
    Bitmap result;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        source.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        result = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Well, this doesn't work either, since the MemoryStream has to be opened during the whole lifetime of Bitmap.

So, I've summed up all my deadends and I'd really like to see a nice elegant way of creating a Bitmap deep copy. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
B.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, B.Width, B.Height), B.PixelFormat)
```

Comment: Works wonderfully for me. No need to serialize/de-serialize on our own.

Comment: For a good discussion of various bitmap cloning options, including how those options work and perform, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935966/3367144).

Comment: This is not a deep copy. The following seems to work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039099/creating-a-completely-new-copy-of-bitmap-from-a-bitmap-in-c-sharp/43042865#43042865

Comment: Not a deep copy, still image data is shared. If I dispose object B the data cloned also gone

Answer (score 2):

Another way I stumbled on that achieves the same thing is to rotate or flip the image. Under the hood that seems to create a completely new copy of the bitmap. Doing two rotations or flips lets you end up with an exact copy of the original image.

```
result.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
result.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
```

Comment: so you copy twice

Answer (score 2):

My environment:Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, Framework 4.5.2

It works for me.

```
Bitmap deepCopy = new Bitmap(original);
```

Comment: This doesn't copy the pixel format of the original bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize the bitmap and then deserialize it. Bitmap is serializable.

Comment: +1 - This is exactly how I've got around the Shallow copy vs. deep copy issue in the past

Comment: -1, because there is no need to serialize (At least not in .NET 4.0). See @George Duckett's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the following class in your code:

```
public static class BitmapExtensions
{
    public static Bitmap DeepClone(this Bitmap source)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (Bitmap)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is adjusted to work with `Bitmap`. If you want to have a generic method look into the link below. By naming the method `DeepClone()` we remove the risk of breaking already existing code (in the answer below the method is called `Clone()`, so it's a override method).

Original from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042865/13574233

This method takes a lot of time though. If you're looking for a good performing method, this probably isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already have a bitmap called original with something in it

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap( 200, 200 );     
Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(copy))
{
  Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, copy.Width, copy.Height);
  graphics.DrawImage( original, imageRectangle, imageRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

This should create a copy of the same size, and draw the original into the copy.

Comment: It loses the original colour format though. The result will always be 32bpp ARGB.

Comment: Addendum to Nyerguds comment: If you try to preserve the original pixel format format by creating the copy using New Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat), you can then run into the issue that Graphics objects can't be created from indexed pixel formats.

Comment: Try [saving to a stream if you want to change the format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_)

Comment: @NigelHawkins [I got around that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170549/395685), though :)