# Creating a completely new copy of bitmap from a bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, deep-copy

I need a deep copy of bitmap from another bitmap. Now, most of the solutions say something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882913/5330223), which is not a **deep copy**. Meaning that when I lock the original bitmap, then the copy gets locked too, as the clone is a **shallow copy** of the original bitmap. Now the following seems to work for me, but I am not sure that will work in all cases.

```
public static Bitmap GetCopyOf(Bitmap originalImage)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height);
    Bitmap retrunImage = new Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, originalImage.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData srcData = originalImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, originalImage.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData destData = retrunImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, originalImage.PixelFormat);
    int dataLength = Math.Abs(srcData.Stride) * srcData.Height;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
    Marshal.Copy(srcData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, destData.Scan0, data.Length);
    destData.Stride = srcData.Stride;
    if (originalImage.Palette.Entries.Length != 0)
        retrunImage.Palette = originalImage.Palette;
    originalImage.UnlockBits(srcData);
    retrunImage.UnlockBits(destData);
    return retrunImage;
}
```

I need better and more elegant way of doing this. Otherwise, just point me some cases where the above code may fail. TIA

Comment: As for more elegant you can try using `BinaryFormatter` to serialize to `MemoryStream` and deserialize from it as new `Bitmap`; it depends on required performance if it is acceptable to you.

Comment: I think that is a good idea. Thanks. I will need to try on that. This performance drop is not a deal breaker for me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem by using this snippet. The idea was given by [Lanorkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2170171/lanorkin) in the comment and the implementaion is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/5330223). Hope this will help somebody later.

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
    }

    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this it is smaller and more elegant way.

```
public static Bitmap GetCopyOf(Bitmap originalImage)
    {
    Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(copy))
    {
      Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, copy.Width, copy.Height);
      graphics.DrawImage( originalImage, imageRectangle, imageRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return copy;
    }
```

Comment: This way the pixel format gets changed. Say the original image is of 8 bit indexed can get to 24 bit Indexed format and some other properties too, otherwise this would be a good solution. Thanks

Comment: Bitmap has a rich collection of constructors, one of which is the following:
Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, originalImage.PixelFormat);
Check the available constructors - I guess you'll find options for the other properties as well.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that way too. but the problem was `Graphics.FromImage(...)` method can not handle all types of images (e.g. images with 8bpp indexed pixel format). I have submitted an `answer`, which seems to eliminate all those problems. Thanks

Comment: Downvote because it doesn't clone the bitmap's properties.