# Does ImageProcessor ImageFactory Load System.Drawing.Image modify by reference argument

Tags: imageprocessor

`ImageProcessor` `ImageFactory` supports Load method with argument `System.Drawing.Image`. But Save method does not support similar argument. Is there a way with `ImageProcessor` `ImageFactory` to `Load` a `System.Drawing.Image`, manipulate the image, e.g., Brightness, then Save the modified image to `System.Drawing.Image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a reference to the original image since that is tightly bound to the input stream.

You can either. 
1. Save to the output stream and use Image.FromStream to create a new image.
2. Use a binary formatter to perform a deep clone of the `ImageFactory.Image` property https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042865/427899