# Immutable method to modify bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, immutability

I wrote simple extension to draw things on `Bitmap`:

```
public static void Fill(this Bitmap src, Contour contour, Color color, int xOffset = 0, int yOffset = 0)
{
    foreach (var point in contour.Points)
    {
        src.SetPixel(point, color, xOffset, yOffset);
    }
}
```

Then I realized, that this method is changing the `src` object, which is problematic for me. I changed this method to:

```
public static Bitmap Fill(this Bitmap src, Contour contour, Color color, int xOffset = 0, int yOffset = 0)
{
    var dst = new Bitmap(src);

    foreach (var point in contour.Points)
    {
        dst.SetPixel(point, color, xOffset, yOffset);
    }

    return dst;
}
```

Now, `src` object is immutable. Unfortunately, now my method is not working properly. No changes are aplied to `dst` object. Why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. We cannot see how you use your method or how you use the bitmap you created.

Comment: You say that the first method was *'changing the `src` object, which is problematic'*. Did it produce the expected results on the bitmap though?

Comment: Also, just as an aside - since Bitmap is a mutable object, I would expect the `Fill` method to mutate the bitmap that it operates on. I think it would be more consistent if you keep the first method, and make a separate `Clone` extension method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Bitmap deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882815/how-to-create-a-bitmap-deep-copy)