# Open Image from file, then release lock?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, locking

I'm using the following line of code to open an `Image` from a file:

```cs
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("test.png");
```

I expect it to lock the file, load the image to memory, set `pictureBox1.Image` to the copy in memory, and release the lock. In reality, the lock won't go away until I `Dispose()` of the `Image` in memory. I can not release the lock on the file on the harddrive that I am no longer using until I get rid of the file in *memory* that I *am* using.
Microsoft's site mentions it in a C#-labeled article, but their solution is written in *visual basic*, which is useless to me.

In summary:
I want to set `pictureBox1.Image` to the image stored in `"test.png"`, then let the user edit or delete `"test.png"` or whatever.

Comment: The advantage of .Net is that a VB code is easy to translate to C#, and vice-versa : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Your image is a GIF? Current answers in this entry won't work for that. See this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017675/354756

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The approach with stream **is not correct**.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8701748/355264

Correct code from above link:

```
Image img;
using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap("image_file_path"))
{
    img = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
}
```

Comment: For a good discussion of what's going on, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935966/3367144).  Notably, the `.Clone()` method will keep the file locked, even after the original is `.Disposed()`.  Copy-constructed clones, as in this answer, are the way to do it.

Comment: [Better approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7972963/199364) if you want to retain the PixelFormat of the original bitmap.

Answer (score 53):

Or better yet, use a `using` statement (the code below is otherwise copied from sylon's [deleted] post). This way if the `Image.FromStream` throws an exception, you can still be assured that the stream is immediately closed.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: VERY bad. You never do this, it will cause issues later. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701748/355264

Comment: Passersby, **do not do this**.  It is better to copy-construct the `Image` or `Bitmap` after opening it, then `.Dispose()` the one used to open from a file.  That will release the file lock.  Note that a `.Clone()` copy will keep the file locked, even after the original is `.Disposed()`.  Copy-constructed copies will release the file lock.  [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935966/3367144)

Comment: If you do it this way, you will get GDI+ errors and also "OutOfMemory" errors if you try to .Clone() the image.

Comment: I like this approach because there is a third parameter to FileStream in .NET 4.6.2/4.7 and .NET Core which allows releasing the lock while reading to allow multiple users to Read the Same File Concurrently.  However, I use ImageMagick for conversions.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use a stream to read the image then close the stream.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest ever way I found is to freeze the object that contains the Source (path to the file). All controls that can contain an image, seem to have a .Source which, if not null, it will lock the file it points to.

Now the trick is to change the Image control to a "read-only" state, which then unlocks the file.

My solution:

```
    private Image CreatePreviewImage()
    {
        Image ReportImage = new Image();
        Uri path = new Uri(@"C:\Folder\Image1.png");
        if (File.Exists(path.OriginalString))
        {
            ReportImage.Name = "Report1";
            ReportImage.Source = LoadImageFromFile(path);
        }
        return ReportImage;
    }

    public ImageSource LoadImageFromFile(Uri path)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = path;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 900;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        bitmap.Freeze(); //This is the magic line that releases/unlocks the file.
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: `BitmapImage` is a WPF class; the original question is about WinForms `Bitmap`.  Nice to see that, if one is using WPF, `BitmapImage` provides a solution to this long-standing annoyance.

Answer (score -1):

talking open, read and release

```
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("picture.png");
    Bitmap tmpBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(streamReader.BaseStream);
    streamReader.Close();
    pictureBox1.Image = tmpBitmap;`
```

Comment: what do you mean by "talking open"?

Comment: i just read the Main Question "Open Image File", so i assume the first action is locating the image file to get the path and filename.. am i wrong to understand the question?

Comment: the 4 lines codes is consist of "Open" as 1st Line, "Read" as 2nd Line, "Release" as 3rd line. And additional 4th line to show the result.

Comment: It seems like a good answer, I simply don't know what you mean by "talking"

Comment: This seems similar to [lahsrah's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576383/199364) from five years earlier.