# Bitmap files save works first time but not second time?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I've looked for answers to this but can't figure out what's going wrong, basically the screencapture function below which creates and saves a bitmap to a file works fine the first time but throws this error when call a second time?? "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

```
    public void Capture(int size, int x, int y, string fname)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(size,size))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(x,
                     y,
                     0, 0,
                     bmpScreenCapture.Size,
                     CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                bmpScreenCapture.Save(fname, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try deleting the file first.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with that simple code. Do you maybe load the image from the filename? Loading a Bitmap from a file locks the file and can cause that error.

Comment: Yes, I did this in another method "Image.FromFile(fname)", how do I ensure the image is not locked?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576341/open-image-from-file-then-release-lock) shows how to load an image without locking it.