# How to solve IOException was unhalted in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public Form1()
{
    String _inputfile = @"C:\Input\cea.tif";

    InitializeComponent();

    pb_picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pb_picturebox.ClientSize = new Size(515, 515);
    pb_picturebox.Image = null;

    pb_picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(_inputfile);

    GeoTiffReader tiff = new GeoTiffReader(_inputfile); // <- IOException was...
    IList<IGeometry> result = tiff.ReadToEnd();
    tiff.Close();
}
```

I get an IOException was unhalted error. 
How should I handle this problem? It works with different file names.

This code sample is cause the exception in GeoTiffReader class:

```
// open the stream for reading
try
{
    _baseStream = FileSystem.GetFileSystemForPath(_path).OpenFile(_path.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // open the file specified by path
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new IOException("Exception occured during stream opening.", ex);
}
```

Watch:
name: ex
value: {"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Input\cea.tif' because it is being used by another process."}

Comment: `try { ... } catch(IOException) { ... }` maybe?

Comment: this line throws the exception:

_baseStream = FileSystem.GetFileSystemForPath(_path).OpenFile(_path.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

i think because the Image.FromFile locks the file or something.

Comment: you need to catch the exception and parse through it to find the cause. It'll provide more specific information.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576645/2655508](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576645/2655508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6576645/2655508

Replace this line

```
pb_picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(_inputfile);
```

with this lines

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(_inputfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    pb_picturebox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

By using the [`using` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) the stream will be disposed as soon as the execution leaves the `using` block and the file isn`t locked any more.