# deleting image files locked by vshost.exe c#

Tags: c#, file, sharing, filelock

I have a c# application which shows images in a form. I'm trying to overwrite these images and regenerate them. I get an exception while I'm trying to delete an existing image (it's a png in this case). I tried disposing the image that the picturebox is using and then setting it to null, but I still get an exception due to a sharing violation. Nevertheless, I can go to explorer and delete the file without any problem.

In trying to figure out what process has this image locked, Process Monitor tells me it's the `vhost.exe` which is hosting my application.

How can I get around this? Is there some way I can get the host to release the lock on the file so that I can delete/recreate it? Ultimately I have large number of images which are generated as thumbnails which would need updating anytime my database incurs changes which affect the graphics. I'd hate to think I need to call a command shell to do this.

Thanks for any advice.

Gary

Comment: vshost.exe is *your* program.  The vshost part is a debugging artifact.  You are surely missing a dispose call somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try loading images using file streams and closing them after reading.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("ImageName.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
yourPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
```

Or instead of explicitly closing; you can employ `using` statement;

```
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("ImageName.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    yourPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it makes no difference. I also disabled the use of vshost.exe, but then it just gets locked by the application itself.

Comment: This will still give errors when manipulating images opened this way, though. If they're opened from a backing resource (like a file _or_ a stream), they will _always_ assume that that resource still exists. The only way around this is [a deep clone of the image data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170549/395685)