# How to write text on top of an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

What I am trying to do is save a picture from a webcam which is attached to my computer, write a string on top of that picture, and save the file. The way my program runs is first it takes a picture, and then I want to be able to write on top of it. Here is the code I have so far to write on top of my saved image, but it throws an 'ExternalException'.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\CamApp\\" + filename + ".jpeg");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.DrawString("HELLO", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));
myBitmap.Save("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\CamApp\\" + filename + ".jpeg",
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you save it to a different file name does it work?

Comment: @David yeah when I change the name it works. How do I save it to the same name then?

Comment: What was the message or code in the ExternalException?

Comment: @SimonLaing The message is "A generic error occurred in GDI+." ErrorCode:-2147467259

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes at the very last line when I am trying to save

Comment: Which seems to confirm David's answer.

Comment: On msdn it states that an external exception will be thrown if you save to the same file you load from. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is discussed in this other question: [Free file locked by new Bitmap(filePath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803935/free-file-locked-by-new-bitmapfilepath)

When you use the `Bitmap` constructor that takes a filename, the file is locked until the `Bitmap` is disposed.  This keeps you from overwriting that image file.

You can use @Brian's answer on the question above to load a `Bitmap` without leaving the file locked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837330/34208

Once you load the image using this method, you'll be able to save over the original file.

**Edit with code sample:**

Replace your line...

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\CamApp\\" + filename + ".jpeg");
```

with

```
Bitmap myBitmap = FromFile(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\CamApp\" + filename + ".jpeg");
```

and make sure to copy over the `FromFile` method from the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I understand that the file is locked but I am confused as to how I would use this method in my code. Do I do something along the lines of:

'Bitmap myBitmap = new Image(src)'