# Delete image after it has been Drag/Drop on form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to delete an image once it has been dragged and dropped on to a windows form.  Below is how I am handling the drag and drop:

```
private void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var paths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(paths[0]);

        var newPath = paths[0].Substring(paths[0].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        bm.Save(newPath);

        pictureEdit1.Image = new Bitmap(newPath);
    }

    private void OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
```

If I try to delete the original image from Windows Explorer I get the "this file is in use" error.  I have tried calling Dispose on `bm` bitmap, but that does not seem to help.

edit: To clarify, when I was calling Dispose, I was calling it right after the `bm.Save(newPath` section and still gives me the error mentioned.

Comment: You don't dispose your bitmaps.

Comment: That's fine, but how do I release the handle the app has on it?

Comment: By disposing the bitmaps. See for example [Free file locked by new Bitmap(filePath)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803935/free-file-locked-by-new-bitmapfilepath).

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Tried that as the question mentioned.  I removed it from the code since it didn't help.  Maybe ill try it again.

Comment: `bm = new Bitmap(paths[0])` locks the file at `paths[0]` until you dispose the bitmap referenced by `bm`, there's little more to make of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the bitmap in a using block like below.

```
private void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var paths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    using(var bm = new Bitmap(paths[0]))
    {
        var newPath = paths[0].Substring(paths[0].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        bm.Save(newPath);
    }
    // using block is all done, handle should be released. delete that bad boy.
    File.Delete(paths[0]); 

    pictureEdit1.Image = new Bitmap(newPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a hiccup in VS.  I re-added the `Dispose` logic and got the same error.  Finally I shut down VS and restarted it, tried again and it worked.