# File.Delete on bitmap doesn't work because the file is being used by another process (I used bitmap.Dispose();)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, bitmap, dispose, delete-file

I'm creating a Windows Forms Application in C#.

I have some buttons on the form and I used the `BackgroundImage` property to set  bitmap images on them.

I wanted to change those images dynamiclly so:

1. I used `using (bitmap = new Bitmap...)` and saved a new bitmap picture.
2. I assign the new bitmap to be on the button.
3. Then, I tried to delete the old bitmap by calling `Dispose()` and then `System.IO.File.Delete(nameToDelete)`;

The problem: the `File.Delete` function throws an exception: *"file is being used by another process"* and I can't delete it.

I also tried calling `GC.Collect()` and assigning the bitmap to `null` but it didn't work.

The only "solution" I find is to call `Thread.Sleep(2)` before deleting, But it's a patch and doesn't work each time.

Here is the code (layerPics[z] is an array that holds all the bitmaps, one for each button):

```
string name = "new name";
Bitmap bitmap;
using (bitmap = new Bitmap(x, y))
{
    Form.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
    bitmap.Save(name);
    button.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(name);
}
layerPics[z].Dispose();
layerPics[z] = null;
layerPics[z] = bitmap;
```

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post formatted code, so we can see where you try the `Dispose` and where the scope of your `using` starts/ends, please?

Comment: Try Thread.Sleep(2000) :)

Comment: Never use `Application.DoEvents()`. It's evil!

Comment: ...an never rely on `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: I just added the relevant code to the original questions. The layerPics[z] array is of type Image[], but it holds bitmap picture.

Comment: `Image.FromFile(name);` will create an object which keeps `name` open until it's disposed. Try doing `if (Buttons.BackgroundImage != null) Buttons.BackgroundImage.Dispose()` before assigning the new bitmap.

Comment: Do you have Explorer open on the directory that contains the image? Or something similar, like Total Commander? Those are usually quite enough to block deleting the file while they generate e.g. thumbnails - instead of just using `Thread.Sleep`, you should simply try deleting the file a few times, with timeouts in between. That said, why are you saving the file in the first place if you want to delete it right after?

Comment: For reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170549/395685) is a workaround for the locking problem, which simply copies all byte data from the opened image into a new Bitmap object and then releases the original resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `Bitmap` that causes the problem, but this line:

```
Buttons.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(name);
```

Here, you create an instance of an `Image` class using the factory method `FromFile()`. The file remains locked until the `Image` is disposed.

This is [the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx).