# rotated image in a picturebox shows rotated and original form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I'm a begginer using VB.Net framework 4.7.2 Winforms.
Im trying to rotate an image of a plane in my application , but it shows the rotated one and the original.

[image: Picture]

left picture is not rotated and the right is rotated at -25°

```
    Private Sub Rotation(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        With e.Graphics
            .TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Width \ 2, PictureBox1.Height \ 2)
            .RotateTransform(dgr)
            .DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, (-PictureBox1.Width \ 2), (-PictureBox1.Height \ 2))
        End With
    End Sub
```

This is the code I rotate the image with

I want just the rotated image shown.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: clear the graphics first.

Comment: Don't use the PictureBox.Image property. Assign that Image to a Bitmap object and use `Graphics.DrawImage()` to draw it on the PictureBox's surface. In this context, you could try the [`Matrix.RotateAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.rotateat) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate, if you assign an `Image` object to the `Image` property of the `PictureBox` then the control will draw that `Image` itself every time.  If you then draw that same `Image` object yourself in the `Paint` event handler then of course you see two images.

Basically, don't assign anything to the `Image` property of the control but rather to your own `Image` field and use that in the `Paint` event handler:

```
Private myImage As Image

Private Sub Rotation(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    With e.Graphics
        .TranslateTransform(PictureBox1.Width \ 2, PictureBox1.Height \ 2)
        .RotateTransform(dgr)
        .DrawImage(myImage, (-PictureBox1.Width \ 2), (-PictureBox1.Height \ 2))
    End With
End Sub
```

You would set `myImage` in code wherever you're currently setting `PictureBox1.Image` or in the `Load` event handler if you're currently setting it in the designer.

Comment: The size of the Image and the canvas should also be considered. To *simulate* the PictureBox's Stretch mode, the `DrawImage()` overload that allows to specify a source Rectangle and a destination Rectangle is good enough. For the Zoom mode, there's a general purpose method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726707/7444103)