# How to draw a transparent shape over an Image

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

How do I draw a shape over an image to overwrite what's there and make it transparent?
Like the transparent hole in the middle of the image below.

[image]

Edit:

I generally use `Graphics.FromImage(image)` when drawing, i.e.

```
Graphics.FromImage(image).DrawRectangle(...)
```

but I want to make a transparent hole or rectangle in the middle of an image.

Comment: Where is the image? In a picturebox? Is it drawn directly on the form? Besides, drawing an image on another to make the latter transparent doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: Does [clipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-clipping-with-a-region) seem like what you want?

Comment: If you build a GraphicsPath with the Circle, you can then create a Region from that GraphicsPath.  Afterwards, you can pass that Region to [ExcludeClip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.excludeclip?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Graphics_ExcludeClip_System_Drawing_Region_) so that when you draw the apple it won't appear in that circle...

Comment: If you want the Form itself to be literally missing in that spot, then you can create a Region representing the whole rectangle, subtract the circle, and then set the Form's Region() property to that.  You'd use [Region.Exclude()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.region.exclude?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Region_Exclude_System_Drawing_Drawing2D_GraphicsPath_) along with some GraphicsPath instances.

Comment: This *concept* is applied here: [How to crop an elliptical region of an Image with smooth borders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61554272/7444103) (it just depends on what you draw first). No Regions and no Clipping are used, to render with better anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method makes use of two [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) objects and a [TextureBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.texturebrush) to draw transparent *holes* inside a Bitmap (see the description of this functionality in the `Worker methods` part).

When the Bitmap we want to work with is loaded, (here, using [File.ReadAllBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes) and a `MemoryStream` to avoid locking the image file on disk), it's assigned to a private Field, **`drawingBitmap`** which is then cloned to create the object shown in a `PictureBox.Image` property (the original Image is always duplicated in a way or another, we never modify it).

▶ The **`selectionRect`** Field keeps track of the area selected (with different means, as shown in the visual sample).

▶ The **`shapeOfHole`** Field is an Enumerator that specifies the type of the shape that `selectionRect` is describing (here, a Rectangle or an Ellipse, but it could be any other shape: using GraphicsPaths as containers makes it even simpler to add polygon shapes).

▶ The **`preserveImage`** boolean Field is a selector used to determine whether the new *holes* are added to the existing Image or a new *hole* is created each time.

In the sample code here, two Buttons, **`btnLoadImage`** and **`btnPaintHole`** are used to activate the main functions (loading and assigning the Image and drawing one or more *holes* in the selected Bitmap).

**`picCanvas`** is the PictureBox used to show the Image.

```
Private drawingBitmap As Image = Nothing
Private selectionRect As RectangleF = New RectangleF(100, 100, 50, 50)
Private shapeOfHole As ShapeType = ShapeType.Rectangle
Private preserveImage as Boolean = False

Private Sub btnLoadImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadImage.Click
    Dim imagePath As String = [Your Image Path]
    drawingBitmap = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath)))
    picCanvas.Image?.Dispose()
    picCanvas.Image = DirectCast(drawingBitmap.Clone(), Bitmap)
End Sub

Private Sub btnPaintHole_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPaintHole.Click
    Dim newImage As Image = Nothing
    If preserveImage AndAlso picCanvas.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        newImage = DrawHole(picCanvas.Image, picCanvas, selectionRect, shapeOfHole)
    Else
        newImage = DrawHole(drawingBitmap, picCanvas, selectionRect, shapeOfHole)
    End If

    If newImage IsNot Nothing Then
        picCanvas.Image?.Dispose()
        picCanvas.Image = newImage
    End If
End Sub
```

**Visual sample of the functionality**:

[image: GraphicsPath Draw Holes]

<sub>▶ The [Image used as the PictureBox.BackgroundImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC60v.png) to simulate the classic *transparent background*</sub> .

**Worker methods**:

▶ The **`DrawHole()`** method uses two [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) objects.
The **`imagePath`** object is sized as the original Image, the **`selectionPath`** object is sized as the current selection area (will be scaled to match the Image real size after).

Using the [FillMode.Alternate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.fillmode) mode, the [imagePath.AddPath(selectionPath, True)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addpath) method sets the **`connect`** argument to `True`, specifying that the added `selectionPath` becomes part of `imagePath`. Since `FillMode.Alternate` is an XOR operation, we *create a hole* in `imagePath`.

The [Graphics.FillPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath) method then uses a [TextureBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.texturebrush) to fill the GraphicsPath, except the XOR-ed part, with the Bitmap object, which will then contain an anti-aliased transparent area (the Graphics object uses the `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` mode).

▶ The **`GetScaledSelectionRect()`** method uses a trick to simplify the calculation of the unscaled coordinates of the selection Rectangle inside a scaled Image (the PictureBox Control `SizeMode` is most probably set to `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`): it reads the .Net PictureBox class [ImageRectangle](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,431) property (who knows why, `private`), to determine the Image scaled bounds and calculates the offset and scale of the selection rectangle based on this measure.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

Friend Enum ShapeType
    Rectangle
    Ellipse
End Enum

Friend Function DrawHole(srcImage As Image, canvas As PictureBox, holeShape As RectangleF, typeOfShape As ShapeType) As Image
    Dim cropped = New Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    Dim imageRect = New RectangleF(Point.Empty, srcImage.Size)
    Dim selectionRect = GetScaledSelectionRect(canvas, holeShape)

    Using tBrush = New TextureBrush(srcImage),
        imagePath = New GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate),
        selectionPath = New GraphicsPath(),
        g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped)

        Select Case typeOfShape
            Case ShapeType.Ellipse
                selectionPath.AddEllipse(selectionRect)
            Case ShapeType.Rectangle
                selectionPath.AddRectangle(selectionRect)
        End Select
        imagePath.AddRectangle(imageRect)
        imagePath.AddPath(selectionPath, True)
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        g.FillPath(tBrush, imagePath)
        Return cropped
    End Using
End Function

Friend Function GetScaledSelectionRect(canvas As PictureBox, selectionRect As RectangleF) As RectangleF
    If canvas.Image Is Nothing Then Return selectionRect
    Dim flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.GetProperty

    Dim imageRect = DirectCast(canvas.GetType().GetProperty("ImageRectangle", flags).GetValue(canvas), Rectangle)

    Dim scaleX = CSng(canvas.Image.Width) / imageRect.Width
    Dim scaleY = CSng(canvas.Image.Height) / imageRect.Height

    Dim selectionOffset = RectangleF.Intersect(imageRect, selectionRect)
    selectionOffset.Offset(-imageRect.X, -imageRect.Y)
    Return New RectangleF(selectionOffset.X * scaleX, selectionOffset.Y * scaleY,
        selectionOffset.Width * scaleX, selectionOffset.Height * scaleY)
End Function
```

---

**C# version**:

```cs
private Image drawingBitmap = null;
private RectangleF selectionRect = new RectangleF(100, 100, 50, 50);
private ShapeType shapeOfHole = ShapeType.Rectangle;
private bool preserveImage = false;

private void btnLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imagePath = [Your Image Path];
    drawingBitmap = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath)));
    picCanvas.Image?.Dispose();
    picCanvas.Image = drawingBitmap.Clone() as Bitmap;
}

private void btnPaintHole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image newImage = null;
    if (preserveImage && picCanvas.Image != null) {
        newImage = DrawHole(picCanvas.Image, picCanvas, selectionRect, shapeOfHole);
    }
    else {
        newImage = DrawHole(drawingBitmap, picCanvas, selectionRect, shapeOfHole);
    }

    if (newImage != null) {
        picCanvas.Image?.Dispose();
        picCanvas.Image = newImage;
    }
}
```

**Worker methods**:

Note: `GetScaledSelectionRect()`, as described, uses Reflection to read the PictureBox `private` **`ImageRectangle`** property from the .Net control.
Since this method is called from the drawing procedure, it's probably better to re-implement this method in a custom PictureBox control, or perform the calculations without invoking [the underlying method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,437) (reflection is not as slow as sometimes advertised, but it's of course slower than using some math directly, here).

Some possible implementations are shown (for example) here:
[Zoom and translate an Image from the mouse location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/7444103)
[Translate Rectangle Position in a Picturebox with SizeMode.Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53800328/7444103)

```cs
internal enum ShapeType {
    Rectangle,
    Ellipse
}

internal Image DrawHole(Image srcImage, PictureBox canvas, RectangleF holeShape, ShapeType typeOfShape)
{
    var cropped = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var imageRect = new RectangleF(Point.Empty, srcImage.Size);
    RectangleF selectionRect = GetScaledSelectionRect(canvas, holeShape);

    using (var tBrush = new TextureBrush(srcImage))
    using (var imagePath = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate))
    using (var selectionPath = new GraphicsPath())
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped)) {

        switch (typeOfShape) {
            case ShapeType.Ellipse:
                selectionPath.AddEllipse(selectionRect);
                break;
            case ShapeType.Rectangle:
                selectionPath.AddRectangle(selectionRect);
                break;
        }
        imagePath.AddRectangle(imageRect);
        imagePath.AddPath(selectionPath, true);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.FillPath(tBrush, imagePath);
        return cropped;
    }
}

internal RectangleF GetScaledSelectionRect(PictureBox canvas, RectangleF selectionRect)
{
    if (canvas.Image == null) return selectionRect;
    var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty;

    var imageRect = (Rectangle)canvas.GetType().GetProperty("ImageRectangle", flags).GetValue(canvas);
    var scaleX = (float)canvas.Image.Width / imageRect.Width;
    var scaleY = (float)canvas.Image.Height / imageRect.Height;

    var selectionOffset = RectangleF.Intersect(imageRect, selectionRect);
    selectionOffset.Offset(-imageRect.X, -imageRect.Y);

    return new RectangleF(selectionOffset.X * scaleX, selectionOffset.Y * scaleY, 
        selectionOffset.Width * scaleX, selectionOffset.Height * scaleY);
}
```