# C# Bitmap cannot display colorbars properly

Tags: c#, winforms, video, bitmap

I would like to display standard TV Colorbars in my WinForms app,

I am generating them on the fly using this function (I translated this from C sources)

```
public void GeneratePixel(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)
{
    int[] bars = new int[]{
        0x000000,   //Black
        0x0000BF,   //Blue
        0xBF0000,   //Red
        0xBF00BF,   //Magenta
        0x00BF00,   //Green
        0x00BFBF,   //Cyan
        0xBFBF00,   //Yellow-green
        0xFFFFFF    //White
    };

    int c = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int pixelPosition = y * width + x;

            if (y < height)
            {
                /* colour bars */
                c = 7 - x * 8 / width;
                c = bars[c];
            }

            buffer[pixelPosition] = (byte)c;
        }
    }

}
```

the output from this function is 24bit array with colors like this: 0xRRGGBB
eg: 0xFFB0C0 is 0xFF for red, 0xB0 for green, 0xC0 for blue. (this is just an example how colors are packed)

they should look like this
[image: Colorbars]

so I tried to draw this exacly as on the picture with Bitmap

**VideoWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ColorBars
{
    public partial class VideoWindow : Form
    {
        int _pictureWidth = 400;
        int _pictureHeight = 625;

        private int _oldVideoWindowWidth;
        private int _oldVideoWindowHeight;
        public VideoWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        public void DrawFrame(byte[] buf, int width, int height)
        {
            this.videoPanel.BufferToBitmap(buf, width, height);
            this.videoPanel.Refresh();
        }

        private void VideoWindows_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            this._oldVideoWindowWidth = control.Size.Width;
            this._oldVideoWindowHeight = control.Size.Height;
        }
        private void VideoWindows_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            int width = control.Size.Width;
            int height = control.Size.Height;
            if (this._oldVideoWindowWidth != width && this._oldVideoWindowHeight == height)
            {
                height = width / 4 * 3;
            }
            else if (this._oldVideoWindowWidth == width && this._oldVideoWindowHeight != height)
            {
                width = height / 3 * 4;
            }
            else
            {
                height = width / 4 * 3;
            }
            control.Size = new Size(width, height);
        }

        public void GeneratePixel(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)
        {
            int[] bars = new int[]{
                0x000000,   //Black
                0x0000BF,   //Blue
                0xBF0000,   //Red
                0xBF00BF,   //Magenta
                0x00BF00,   //Green
                0x00BFBF,   //Cyan
                0xBFBF00,   //Yellow-green
                0xFFFFFF    //White
            };

            int c = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int pixelPosition = y * width + x;

                    if (y < height)
                    {
                        /* colour bars */
                        c = 7 - x * 8 / width;
                        c = bars[c];
                    }

                    buffer[pixelPosition] = (byte)c;
                }
            }

        }

        private void DisplayUpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] videoBufferPtr = new byte[this._pictureWidth * this._pictureHeight];

            GeneratePixel(videoBufferPtr, this._pictureWidth, this._pictureHeight);
            DrawFrame(videoBufferPtr, this._pictureWidth, this._pictureHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

**VideoWindow.Designer.cs**

```
namespace ColorBars
{
    partial class VideoWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        private global::ColorBars.DrawScreen videoPanel;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.DisplayUpdateTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.videoPanel = new ColorBars.DrawScreen();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // DisplayUpdateTimer
            // 
            this.DisplayUpdateTimer.Enabled = true;
            this.DisplayUpdateTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.DisplayUpdateTimer_Tick);
            // 
            // videoPanel
            // 
            this.videoPanel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.videoPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 3);
            this.videoPanel.Name = "videoPanel";
            this.videoPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(421, 323);
            this.videoPanel.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // VideoWindow
            // 
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
            this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 327);
            this.Controls.Add(this.videoPanel);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            this.Name = "VideoWindow";
            this.Text = "Video";
            this.ResizeBegin += new System.EventHandler(this.VideoWindows_ResizeBegin);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.VideoWindows_Resize);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer DisplayUpdateTimer;
    }
}
```

**DrawScreen.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ColorBars
{
    internal class DrawScreen : UserControl
    {
        private Bitmap _buffer;
        private Rectangle _rect;
        public DrawScreen()
        {
            base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            base.UpdateStyles();
        }
        
        public void BufferToBitmap(byte[] buf, int width, int height)
        {
            if (buf == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Rectangle rect = this._rect;
            if (this._rect.Width != width || this._rect.Height != height)
            {
                this._rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            }
            if (this._buffer == null || this._buffer.Width != width || this._buffer.Height != height)
            {
                this._buffer = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed); 
                this._buffer.Palette = this.GetRGBColorPalette();
            }
            BitmapData bitmapData = this._buffer.LockBits(this._rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            IntPtr scan = bitmapData.Scan0;
            Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, scan, buf.Length);
            this._buffer.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }

        //Create the right palette so your testcard will display properly
        private ColorPalette GetRGBColorPalette()
        {
            ColorPalette palette = this._buffer.Palette;
            Color[] entries = palette.Entries;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
            {
                entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);
            }
            return palette;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._buffer == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            int width = this._rect.Width;
            int height = this._rect.Height;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            width -= x;
            height -= y;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this._buffer, e.ClipRectangle, x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I cannot get colorbars to look right

This is how they look (they are not even proper grayscale
[image: My broken color bars]

I tried to change my ColorPallete to be RGB but I am not able to do so

```
private ColorPalette GetRGBColorPalette()
{
    ColorPalette palette = this._buffer.Palette;
    Color[] entries = palette.Entries;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 253; i++)
    {
        entries[i + 0] = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, i, i);  //R
        entries[i + 1] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, 255, i);  //G 
        entries[i + 2] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, 255);  //B
    }
    return palette;
}
```

[image: red cololr bars]

I would just like to create some RGB color palette (not sure if this testcard is even RGB or some YUV or other wierd format), so I can display things on it (my screen) properly

and I have to use PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed ,because if I use anything else like PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb (which seams most apropriate for PAL video) like this

```
public void BufferToBitmap(byte[] buf, int width, int height)
{
    if (buf == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Rectangle rect = this._rect;
    if (this._rect.Width != width || this._rect.Height != height)
    {
        this._rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    if (this._buffer == null || this._buffer.Width != width || this._buffer.Height != height)
    {
        this._buffer = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        //this._buffer.Palette = this.GetRGBColorPalette(); //I had to remove my ColorPallete because I get System.IndexOutOfRangeException with it
    }
    BitmapData bitmapData = this._buffer.LockBits(this._rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    IntPtr scan = bitmapData.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, scan, buf.Length);
    this._buffer.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}
```

then not only that my TestCard still does not have colors, its also to small and it will not fit on the screen
[image: testCard2Small]

and the screen has to have 400x625 resolution because thats the resolution for PAL video

Hopefully someone has an idea how can I display this testcard corecly on this window

Thanks for Anwesring and Best Regards

Comment: Is there a reason why you use pixels? Why don't you use a `LinearGradientBrush` for example?

Comment: I am trying to mimic the CRT display, as I am trying to decode composite video, and first I need to make my screen display colors properly before I can continue, also all modern televisions display pixels when decoding composite video, so I need to make my screen compatible for that)

Comment: @LimePeta, I created a project to make the try, but I still meet the same problem as you, looking forward, then will tell you if I find something

Comment: [How to make colors in a Palette transparent when drawing 8bpp Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498663/7444103) (first snippet - you have 7 columns and 1 row)

Comment: So you want the 7 colors in your image only? And mix other colors from them in adjacent pixels? Then you need a palette with these 7 colors and set only their 7 indices into the bitmap pixels.

Comment: OK, let's make that 8 colors. And the last time I met such a system (in early games and in CGA and EGA) there were another 8 colors which were more subdued, ie either darker or for black brighter, I think.. What will you actual input be/look like=

Comment: This is a standard NTSC/PAL testcard, I need enough colors to cover all the color options and that I can display PAL/NTSC/SECAM signal corecly, I guess if this color bars are displayed corecly, then I am good to go right?

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, very useful link, I also was trying to do that, but I now understand much better with it.