# Winform: how to get PointToClient if sizemode is *CenterImage* and image was scaled on center?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I have panel and picturebox inside. Picturebox in *centerImage* SizeMode, and if image too small for one side, i have empty space between centered image and panel corner. I need to get PointToClient of this image, im using code below, but PointToClient ignore empty space and show me x\y out of real image but as *point of picturebox*. And its looks correct, but is there any way to get real point of image?
Screenshot, red point = where im clickin, and point is below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12uTc.png

```
Point point = picturebox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

And if its not posible, is there any way to resize picturebox with auto-centering on panel (like picture centering on picturebox)

Comment: To simplify all calculations, you can get the value of the `ImageRectangle` property of your PictureBox. It's (for unknown reasons) a `private` Property, so you need to use Reflection to reach it. It returns the scaled bounds of the displayed Image in the current `PictureBoxSizeMode`.

Comment: You can see an implementation here: [How to draw a transparent shape over an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724726/7444103) (in the C# version of that answer). Check the `GetScaledSelectionRect()` method.