# How to disable anti-aliasing when resizing a System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.drawing, antialiasing

I am using a `Bitmap` to load images to PictureBoxes.

```
Dim bm1 As Bitmap = My.Resources.pixelart 'the images width and height is 32
PictureBox1.Size = New Size(200, 200)
PictureBox1.Image = bm1
```

And because of the second line, the image is anti-aliased. How can I turn off this feature?

Comment: ...if you found out how, post it as an answer of your own!´

Comment: Sure i'll post it in few minutes

Comment: Here's a better duplicate, specifically for VB.NET: [Disable Image blending on a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54720916/8967612)