# C# System.Drawing.DrawImage() draws bitmap in wrong place

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, system.drawing

I have a panel control and a bitmap with the same size. When I resize the panel I want the bitmap to be drawn on it. I use DrawImage(Image, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)

This is the panel (Canvas) Paint Event

```
private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, Canvas.Width, Canvas.Height);
        }
```

But the image moves a bit. Looks like the method draws it in (-0.5, -0.5) instead of (0, 0)

[Original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7XdM.png)

[Bitmap on panel (Red pixel is cut and dark grey border appears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mm0G.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: How is the Canvas on the form?

Comment: What happens you you set this Bitmap as the `BackgroundImage` of your Panel? Also setting `BackgroundImageLayout` to what appears to be `Stretch`. --  See also `InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor` and `PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half`

Comment: Some notes about InterpolationMode and PixelOffsetMode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726707/7444103)

Comment: Thank You! It happened because of PixelOffsetMode.