# print Bitmap to A4 size without stretch

Tags: vb.net, printing, bitmap, stretch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmE32.jpg)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

        Dim margX As Single = e.PageSettings.HardMarginX
        Dim margY As Single = e.PageSettings.HardMarginY
        Dim adjustToA4 As New Rectangle(e.PageBounds.Left - margX, e.PageBounds.Top - margY, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)


        Dim dm As New Bitmap(Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height)
        Panel2.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height))

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, adjustToA4)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

    End Sub

End Class
```

This coding allows the bitmap to print to A4 size... but the bitmap is not in its original form in A4 size.
therefore, what is the coding that can enlarge or reduce the bitmap to A4 size without affecting the shape of the bitmap..
thank you...

"translation"....

enlarge or reduce bitmap to A4 size without stretch.... VB 2022

Comment: See the `GetScaledImageRect()` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726707/7444103), it's used to preserve the aspect ratio of the image, based on the container

Comment: I do it this way.. first, I put the image and textbox and so on into the A6 or A7 size panel and backgroundimagelayout = zoom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument2
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim margX As Single = e.PageSettings.HardMarginX
    Dim margY As Single = e.PageSettings.HardMarginY
    Dim adjustToA4 As New Rectangle(e.PageBounds.Left - margX, e.PageBounds.Top - margY, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)

    Dim dm As New Bitmap(Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height)
    Panel2.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height))

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, adjustToA4)

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage
    Dim adjustToA4 As New Rectangle(25, 30, e.PageBounds.Width - 60, e.PageBounds.Height - 50)

    Dim dm As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
    Panel1.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, adjustToA4)
End Sub
```

End Class

[image: Form1]
[image: PrintPreview2]
[image: PrintPreview1]