# OutOfMemoryException was unhandled

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, system.drawing

I change the [Automatic Image Stitching with Accord.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95453/Automatic-Image-Stitching-with-Accord-NET) application to stitch multiple files.
I put a `for loop` at the `btnDoItAll` code, the loop will depend on how many images was to stitch.
I have joined a cropping code at the end of the loop. you can see the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250752/ioexception-was-unhandled).
The an error showed up which said `OutOfMemoryException was unhandled - Out of memory` in this part.

```
croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(MinWidth, 0, (int)croppedBitmap.Width - MinWidth - MaxWidth, 1323), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
```

hope you can help me again.

```
The output from debug was these:  
Bitmap-width: 877
Bitmap-height: 1325
Width: -1
MinWidth: 877
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a reason Image.FromFile throws an OutOfMemoryException for an invalid image format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610416/is-there-a-reason-image-fromfile-throws-an-outofmemoryexception-for-an-invalid-i)

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem a few hours ago check your boundaries for Clone. If you move outside of your bitmap it will throw this exception.

So be careful that this is the case.

```
1: MinWidth + (int)croppedBitmap.Width - MinWidth - MaxWidth <= croppedBitmap.Width
2: 0 + 1323 <= croppedBitmap.Height
```

if my guess is correct 1 & 2 are not fulfilled

EDIT:
Add this in front of Clone and post the result in your post

```
Debug.WriteLine("Bitmap-width: "+croppedBitmap.Width);
Debug.WriteLine("Bitmap-height: "+croppedBitmap.Height);
Debug.WriteLine("Width: "+(croppedBitmap.Width - MinWidth - MaxWidth));
Debug.WriteLine("MinWidth: "+MinWidth);
```

EDIT2:
1. Your width is < 0 (in this case -1) which shouldn't be the case
2. Even if it would be > 0 it would result in an error since 877 + x is > croppedBitmap.Width which is not allowed

So what I was saying from the very beginning is that you have to make sure that your width and height have to be larger 0 AND that the sum of width + MinWidth and height + 0 from your rectangle mustn't exceed the boundaries of your image.

Right now your rectangle looks like this:

```
new Rectangle(877, 0, -1, 1323) // Rectangle(posx, posy, width, height)
```

So as you can see the width is negative which is not what you want it has to be larger 0. So if you would do this now:

```
new Rectangle(877, 0, 1, 1323)
```

It would still be wrong since your rectangle would be from from 877 to 878 (x coordinate) which can't be since your image is only 877 pixels wide. This means `MinWidth` and `(int)croppedBitmap.Width - MinWidth - MaxWidth` are wrong. You have to make sure that your values don't cause these kind of problems.

It's not a problem with the Copy method it's more a problem of the passed parameters. You have to check them before passing them!

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this stuff. I didn't quite get it, what should i suppose to do?

Comment: I've add it in front of `croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(`, there was an error on debbuging which saids `The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Because you need using System.Diagnostics;

Comment: Wrong parameters often cause OOM exceptions with `System.Drawing`. So ensure the chosen rectangle is valid.

Comment: @Layne the cropping application alone does run successfully. but when combining it to the other application results into this. what do you think the problem is?